# js, if number is divisible and not decimal

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a code that counts the meters some dogs have travelled. It's just a gif constantly in loop. Now I wanted to show an image every 50 meters for like 3 seconds.
That's how I have tried it:

```
          if (i % Number.isInteger(50)) {
            document.getElementById("orange").style.display = "block";
          }
```

That's how I've tried it but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: `Number.isInteger(50)` returns `true` ... how do you expect that to be useful for the modulo operator? `i%50 === 0` is probably what you want

Comment: You probably want something like `if(Number.isInteger(i) && i % 50 === 0) { ... }` although I suspect that the `Number.isInteger` check is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FLOOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
let frames = Math.floor(i / 50)
```

That will be `0` until *1==50*, then it'll be `1` until *i==100*.
So 1234 steps will give you 24 frames played.

Then you have to decide how many images you have, lets say 5 images:

```js
let currentImageIndex = iterations % 5;
```

That'll make it it go 0,1,2,3,4,**0**,...
That means in our example: 24%5 = 4, display the 5th image (because `0` is the first, that makes `4` the fifth image).

```js
document.getElementById("my-image").src = `frame${currentImageIndex}.png`;
```

If the person would take a few steps more, 1251 steps, divided by 50 = 25 frames, modulo 5 -> currentImageIndex==0.

*Note*: this is untested, but should give you something to build off of

*Note*: your current solution isn't working because `Number.isInteger(50)` always returns true because 50 is an integer. It doesn't convert anything, it just tests of it is an integer.